# Help understand how these two sentences link together

Tags: meaning

The context is that the person is struggling to figure out how he should respond to the affection from a girl he knows. She hasn't clearly said anything to him but has made her feelings obvious through her actions and what she says. In the below he is wondering how to respond, however I'm unsure how the end of the first part of the sentence leads into the second.

> 僕の方から思いきり甘えてみて(in the line before this he asks for a 膝枕)、それで気持ちが本当なら……
>
> それはそういうことだろうと、僕は自分自身に答えを出せる気がした。

---

I've typed up my understanding of these parts of the sentences below.

それで気持ちが本当なら - If feelings are true ...

それはそういうことだろうと、僕は自分自身に答えを出せる気がした - This is split into two parts, それはそういうことだろうと which is his 答え (I believe meaning that he loves her), and 僕は自分自身に答えを出せる気がした which is him saying that he felt he would be able to come up with this answer.

Comment: I think you pretty much hit the nail on the head. I'd translate 「僕は自分自身に答えを出せる気がした」as "I felt like I could give myself an answer (that...)"